# How to use ES6 and ES7 in my Gruntfile

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I would like to use ES6 and ES7 in my Gruntfile. The reason is that I would like to write a task, which includes the [git-repository module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-repository). As you can see from the documentation, the module is only available in ES6 and ES7 and I would like to integrate this module as easy as possible. Is there a way that I can use ES6 and ES7 also in my Gruntfile - somthing like `babel grunt`? Unfortunately, I did not find anything on Google and therefore I hope that you can help me.

Thank you in advance! :-)

Comment: one way is to write your file in es6 or es7 then complile it to es5 before executing

Comment: Yes, I know this, but normally there should be a way to write your tasks in ES6 isn`t it?

Comment: You already have ES6 feature set (except ES6 modules) in Node environment. The features you're referring to (async/await) are not standardized and belong to so-called ES.next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you may want to use a build tool to transpile, so this is a 'who will build a build tool' problem.

It isn't usual for public package on NPM to be available only in ES.next or ES6 with feature set that is not supported by Node. `git-repository` isn't exception. It surely has transpiled code in the package and can be used without Babel.

Because the package was transpiled with `babel-plugin-transform-runtime`, it requires `babel-polyfill` to work.

Documentation uses `async...await` only as an example because it suits the workflow. `async` functions use promises, in ES5/ES6 it would be

```
require('babel-polyfill');

Repo.open('./example', { init: true })
.then(repo =>
  repo.setRemote('origin', 'https://github.com/user/example.git')
  .then(() => repo.add('--all .'))
  .then(() => repo.commit('Commit message'))
  ...
);
```

[`co`](https://github.com/tj/co) is excellent alternative to `async...await` for Node ES6 feature set that requires no transpiler.